Is SHA-1 mandatory in Firebase for receiving Google Play in-app purchase
From the Firebase help center it seems that the SHA-1 fingerprint is not a mandatory requirement for general use but might be necessary for the use of Dynamic Links, and Auth. However it was required for linking Firebase with Google Play previously.
Can any Firebase experts help to confirm if it is still mandatory for this linkage? thanks!

Currently, SHA-1 is not required for linking Firebase and Google Play. It is also not necessary to track in-app purchases.
In-app purchase events are automatically tracked by Firebase once a user completes an in-app purchase in your app. Just make sure that you are using the correct version of the Analytics SDK in your app, and Firebase and Google Play are linked together successfully.
If you’re using Dynamic Links and Authentication, you may need to configure SHA-1 fingerprint and add it to your app in the Firebase console.
References:

Firebase Docs: Measure in-app purchases
Firebase Help Center: Link Google Play to Firebase

